# Writing a wrapper of execl() function, got weird result

Tags: c, linux, arguments, exec

I'm trying to write a wrapper of `execl` function, but the command doesn't run (with `execl` directly it works)

Then I added a `vfprintf` for debugging purpose. But vfprintf only prints `/bin/ls`, so I think it's truncated somewhere in the middle.

What's wrong with my code?

```
int my_execl(const char *file, const char *format, ...)
{
    int ret = 0;

    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);
    vfprintf (stdout, format, args);
    ret = execl (file, format, args);
    va_end (args);

    return ret;
}

int main (int argc , char **argv)
{
    my_execl ("/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", "-r", "-t", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no function in the [`exec`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) family which takes a format specification and a `va_list` argument.

Comment: That the `vprintf` only prints `"/bin/ls"` is because that's the format string, there are no actual formatting or extra argument in the string.

Comment: And if you really need to write a wrapper (why would you want that?) you have to construct the argument list manually and call e.g. [`execv`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) with it.

Answer (score 0):

> you have to construct the argument list manually and call e.g. execv
>   with it. – Joachim Pileborg

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int my_execl(const char *file, ...)
{
    int ret;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, file);
    ret = execv(file, (char **)args);
    va_end(args);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: How can you be sure that you can cast a `va_list` to `(char **)`?

Comment: That's a very justified question. Indeed, I can't.

Comment: Given [the structure of va_list on x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958384/what-is-the-format-of-the-x86-64-va-list-structure), I can't see how this would work.