# vfprintf doesn't work properly

Tags: c++, gcc, printing, printf

I have a class:

```
FILE *logFile = fopen("out.log", "w");
class Log {
public:
    static void d(const char *message, ...) __attribute__((format (printf, 1, 2)));
}
```

In source file:

```
void Log::d(const char *message, ...) {
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, message);

    vprintf(message, argptr);
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    if (logFile) {
        vfprintf(logFile, message, argptr);
        fprintf(logFile, "\n");
        fflush(logFile);
    }

    va_end(argptr);
}
```

But when I call for example `Log::d("test %d %s %f", 10, "str", 0.1);` it prints `test 0 @WAíõ 0,000000` to the file.

What's wrong?

Comment: And what does the `DEBUG_D` macro (I suppose?) do?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my mistake, DEBUG_D == Log::d

Comment: Could you please check the return value of the function calls and tell them e.g. of `vfprintf()`. Further you could check the `errno` variable.

Comment: @AndreKampling 22; 1; 0

Comment: What values belongs to which function?

Comment: @AndreKampling from vprintf to fflush. Errno is "No such file or directory" at  every of this function, also.

Comment: Ok but for `errno` you have to set it to `errno = 0` before each call.

Comment: @AndreKampling ok, now it's Success

Comment: Your values are fine then. The 22 are the number bytes written of your wrong string without counting the null byte. What happens if you don't use a `double` but an `int` instead?

Comment: @AndreKampling 
   `Log::d("test %s %f", "str", 0.1) == "test (null) 0,000000"`

    `Log::d("test %s %d", "str", 11) == "test (null) 2062882624"`

    `Log::d("test %d", 11) == "test 0"`

Comment: @AndreKampling I'll be back in a hour

Comment: @AndreKampling do you still want to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using your `va_list` `argptr` 2 times. Once in the `vprintf` and secondly in the `vfprintf` call. How a `va_list` works with the stack is **implementation defined**, see [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg). The `va_list` type for example is implemented in **Linux x86_64** like said [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4958507/8051589):

> **The va_list Type**
>
> The va_list type is an array containing a single element of one structure containing the necessary information to implement the va_arg macro. The C deﬁnition of va_list type is given in ﬁgure 3.34
>
> ```
> // Figure 3.34
> typedef struct {
>    unsigned int gp_offset;
>    unsigned int fp_offset;
>    void *overflow_arg_area;
>    void *reg_save_area;
> } va_list[1];
> ```

If you pass your `va_list` into the first `vprintf` call and the function returns the `va_list` will no longer be as before the call. The second call to `vfprintf` will get a "wrong/consumed `va_list`" then.

**Solution:**

Either use `va_copy` after `va_start` or use `va_start` 2 times if your compiler doesn't support `va_copy`. But remember each call to `va_copy` or `va_start` needs a corresponding call to `va_end`.