# what does overflow_arg_area mean in x86_64 va_list?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, variadic-functions, abi

I am reading this answer [What is the format of the x86_64 va_list structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958384/what-is-the-format-of-the-x86-64-va-list-structure), where there is mention a member of `va_list` -> `void *reg_save_area`, which should be a address of start of the register save area. But as far as I know, there is no save area defined in ABI, since all arguments passed are not pushed but rather saved on register `rdi,rsi,rdx,rcx,..`, which mean the address does not make sense to me, since no argument is passed to memory. I have tried to see it in assembly, So I have compiled code from my previous question [What is -fverbose-asm trying to say in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62478718/what-is-fverbose-asm-trying-to-say-in-assembly?noredirect=1#comment110497575_62478718):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void print_ints(int len, ...){
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, len);

    for(int i =0; i<len ; i++)
    {
        int val = va_arg(args,int);
        printf("i:%i\tval:%i\n",i,val);
    }

    va_end(args);
}

int main(){
    print_ints(2,1,2);
}
```

and got:

```
print_ints:
    pushq   %rbp    #
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
    subq    $224, %rsp  #,
    movl    %edi, -212(%rbp)    # len, len
    movq    %rsi, -168(%rbp)    #,
    movq    %rdx, -160(%rbp)    #,
    movq    %rcx, -152(%rbp)    #,
    movq    %r8, -144(%rbp) #,
    movq    %r9, -136(%rbp) #,
    testb   %al, %al    #
    je  .L7 #,
    ...

    movl    $8, -208(%rbp)  #, MEM[(struct [1] *)&args].gp_offset
    movl    $48, -204(%rbp) #, MEM[(struct [1] *)&args].fp_offset
    leaq    16(%rbp), %rax  #, tmp100
    movq    %rax, -200(%rbp)    # tmp100, MEM[(struct [1] *)&args].overflow_arg_area
    ...
    
main:
    pushq   %rbp    #
    movq    %rsp, %rbp  #,
# a.c:19:   print_ints(2,1,2);
    movl    $2, %edx    #,
    movl    $1, %esi    #,
    movl    $2, %edi    #,
    movl    $0, %eax    #,
    call    print_ints  # THERE IS NO ARGUMENT PASSED TO STACK, 16(%rbp) does not make sense then to be address for reg_save_area
```

So now, the `void *overflow_arg_area` points to the `16(%rbp)`, but there is nothing, since all argument where saved to `rdi,rsi,rdx`(3 arguments). Can someone explain, why does *overflow_arg_area points to random `16(%rbp)`?

Comment: If there were extra arguments passed on the stack, they would be at `16(%rbp)`.  `print_ints` doesn't know how many arguments it's going to receive, so there could be arguments there.

Comment: @fuz why `16(%rbp)`? I know `%rbp==ret`, `8(%rbp)==first_argument`, `16(%rbp)==second_argument`, ... But that is for x32, where args are passed to stack. On x64 there are 6 registers, `di,si,dx,cx,r8,r9`, after which it goes to the stack (not sure with that, never needed more then 6 args), but why `16(%rbp)`??

Comment: Not quite.  After the standard `push %rbp`; mov `%rsp, %rbp` prologue, `rbp` points to the old `rsp`, `rbp+8` points to the return address, and `rbp+16` points to the first argument on the stack.

Comment: @fuz yes, forgot about that one. But anyway, that is for x32, not x64 where args go to regs.

Comment: Even on the amd64 SysV ABI, if there are more than 6 integer arguments, further arguments are passed on the stack.

Comment: Note that the compiler still needs to "pretend" the arguments are passed on the stack if you do such things as taking the address of one the parameters. `va_list` is likely to be another such thing, you need sequential access to all the arguments but the first ones are in the registers and thus cannot be indexed; so the compiler may prefer to spill them in memory with the others. I haven't read the format of `va_list` or that answer. Unless it is specifically for Linux, another thing to check would be the Windows' homing/shadow register space and see if that has something to do with this.

Comment: "But that is for x32, where args are passed to stack" That's wrong. [x32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) passes arguments in registers just like x64. The only real difference between x32 and x64 is the pointer size.

Comment: "But as far as I know, there is no save area defined in ABI" Right, usually there isn't one, but when you call `va_start`, the compiler makes one. (And the details actually are in the ABI, along with `va_list`.)

Comment: "Can someone explain, why does *overflow_arg_area points to random `16(%rbp)`?" If instead of `print_ints(2,1,2);`, you did `print_ints(6,1,2,3,4,5,6);`, where do you think that last `6` would live?