# Is GCC mishandling a pointer to a va_list passed to a function?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

The question ['Pass va_list or pointer to va_list?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369588/pass-va-list-or-pointer-to-va-list) has an answer which quotes the standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999 - §7.15 'Variable arguments `<stdarg.h>`, footnote 212) as explicitly saying that:

> It is permitted to create a pointer to a `va_list` and pass that pointer to another function, in which case the original function may make further use of the original list after the other function returns.

I'm compiling some code which can be exemplified by the following (the real code is very considerably more complex, with the original functions doing a lot more work than shown here).

#### vap.c

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void test_ptr(const char *fmt, va_list *argp)
{
    int x;
    x = va_arg(*argp, int);
    printf(fmt, x);
}

static void test_val(const char *fmt, va_list args)
{
    test_ptr(fmt, &args);
}

static void test(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);   /* First use */
    test_val(fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    va_start(args, fmt);   /* Second use */
    test_ptr(fmt, &args);
    va_end(args);
}

int main(void)
{
    test("%d", 3);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Error messages

When I compile it (on RHEL5 with GCC 4.1.2 or 4.5.1), I get the following error messages.  Notice how much more informative the 4.5.1 error message is - the GCC team is to be congratulated on the improvement!

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.5.1
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc -c vap.c
vap.c: In function ‘test_val’:
vap.c:13:5: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘test_ptr’ from incompatible pointer type
vap.c:4:13: note: expected ‘struct __va_list_tag (*)[1]’ but argument is of type ‘struct __va_list_tag **’
$ /usr/bin/gcc -c vap.c
vap.c: In function ‘test_val’:
vap.c:13: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘test_ptr’ from incompatible pointer type
$
```

I get the same messages on MacOS X Lion with GCC/LLVM 4.2.1 and with GCC 4.6.1:

```
$ /usr/bin/gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.6.1
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$
```

### Questions

- Can someone articulate why the `test_val()` function cannot pass the `va_list` passed as an argument to `test_ptr()`, whereas the `test()` function (which created the `va_list`) can?
- Is GCC correct to complain about the indirect passing of the pointer in `test_val()`?

On both cases, I can see an answer fuzzily, but I can't describe it succinctly.  I think that the code in `test_val()` is abusing the `va_list` and it is good that the code won't compile - but I'd like to be sure before I go fixing it.

---

#### Update 2012-03-30

I went to deal with the problematic code this week.  Before making changes, I went to find where the miscreant functions are used — and they aren't!  So, I solved my compilation error problem by removing the functions (4 externally visible but unused ones, plus 2 static ones which contained the problematic code).  That was much simpler than having to work out how to deal with the mess.  (This also explains why there was never any evidence of a run-time problem caused by the code.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a known problem. On some architectures (in particular x86-64), `va_list` needs to be more complex than a simple pointer to the stack, for example because some arguments might be passed in registers or out-of-band in some other way (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958384/what-is-the-format-of-the-x86-64-va-list-structure/4958507#4958507) for the definition of `va_list` on x86-64).

On such architectures, it is common to make `va_list` an array type so that parameters of type `va_list` will be adjusted to pointer types, and instead of the whole structure, only a single pointer needs to be passed.

This should not violate the C standard, which only says that `va_list` must be a complete object type and even explicitly accounts for the fact that passing a `va_list` argument might not actually clone the necessary state: `va_list` objects have indeterminate value if they are passed as arguments and consumed in the called function.

But even if making `va_list` an array type is legal, it still leads to the problems you experienced: As parameters of type `va_list` have the 'wrong' type, eg `struct __va_list_tag *` instead of `struct __va_list_tag [1]`, it will blow up in cases where the difference between arrays and pointers matter.

The real problem is not the type mismatch gcc warns about, but the by-pointer instead of by-value argument passing semantics: `&args` in `test_val()` points to the intermediate pointer variable instead of the `va_list` object; ignoring the warning means that you'll invoke `va_arg()` in `test_ptr()` on the pointer variable, which should return garbage (or segfault if you're lucky) and corrupt the stack.

One workaround is to wrap your `va_list` in a structure and pass that around instead. Another solution [I've seen in the wild](http://groups.google.com/group/jansson-users/browse_thread/thread/09b467e583aa4059/4a409ee27a2ddea1), even [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958384/what-is-the-format-of-the-x86-64-va-list-structure/4959184#4959184), is to use `va_copy` to create a local copy of the argument and then pass a pointer to that:

```
static void test_val(const char *fmt, va_list args)
{
    va_list args_copy;
    va_copy(args_copy, args);
    test_ptr(fmt, &args_copy);
    va_end(args_copy); 
}
```

*This should work in practice, but technically it might or might not be undefined behaviour, depending on your interpretation of the standard:*

If `va_copy()` is implemented as a macro, no parameter adjustments are performed, and it might matter that `args` is not of type `va_list`. However, as it is *unspecified* whether `va_copy()` is a macro or a function, one might argue that it at least *could* be a function and parameter adjustments are implicitly assumed in the prototype given for the macro. It might be a good idea to ask the officials for clarification or even file a defect report.

You could also use your build system to deal with the issue by defining a configuration flag like `HAVE_VA_LIST_AS_ARRAY` so you can do the right thing for your particular architecture:

```
#ifdef HAVE_VA_LIST_AS_ARRAY
#define MAKE_POINTER_FROM_VA_LIST_ARG(arg) ((va_list *)(arg))
#else
#define MAKE_POINTER_FROM_VA_LIST_ARG(arg) (&(arg))
#endif

static void test_val(const char *fmt, va_list args)
{
    test_ptr(fmt, MAKE_POINTER_FROM_VA_LIST_ARG(args));
}
```

Comment: I would think that even the Standard would allow `va_copy` to be implemented as a function on platforms where doing so would yield correct semantics, it would implicitly require that it be implemented as a macro in cases where the correct semantics could not be otherwise achieved.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is not specific to `va_list`. The following code results in a similar warning:

```
typedef char *test[1];

void x(test *a)
{
}

void y(test o)
{
    x(&o);
}
```

The problem stems from the way C handles function variables that are also arrays, probably due to the fact that arrays are passed as reference and not by value. The type of `o` is not the same as the type of a local variable of type `test`, in this case: `char ***` instead of `char *(*)[1]`.

Returning to the original issue at hand, the easy way to work around it is to use a container struct:

```
struct va_list_wrapper {
    va_list v;
};
```

and there would be no typing problems passing a point to it.

Comment: The sentence starting "The type of `o`" should end in `char **` vs `char *[1]`.  The actual types given are the types of `&o` versus `a`.

Answer (score 8):

As others have noted, this issue manifests itself when `va_list` is an array type.  This is allowed by the standard, which only says that `va_list` must be an *"object type"*.

You can fix the `test_val()` function like so:

```
static void test_val(const char *fmt, va_list args)
{
    va_list args_copy;

    /* Note: This seemingly unnecessary copy is required in case va_list
     * is an array type. */
    va_copy(args_copy, args);
    test_ptr(fmt, &args_copy);
    va_end(args_copy);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think `va_list` must be declared as an array type, which “boils down” to a pointer type when declared as a parameter of a function. Therefore, the `&` applied to the `va_list` type in `test_val` yields a pointer to a pointer type, not a pointer to an array type, however, the `test_ptr` function declares one of its parameters as a pointer to array type, which is what is actually provided in the `test` function.

Comment: Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048892/53974, `va_list` is only an array type on some archs, but that includes x86_64.