# C++: Is it safe to use a va_list type as a class member?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

Is it safe to use a va_list type as a class member?

The below example works in Solaris. It doesn't need to be portable across different operating systems. But is it portable to future Solaris versions? Different HW? Different compilers? Or compiler options?

```
class MyFormatString
{
public:
     MyFormatString(const char* formatString, va_list varg);
     ~MyFormatString() { va_end(mVarg); }
     // ... 
     // provide some util functions to operate on the format string
     // ...
private:
     string mFormatString;
     va_list mVarg;
};

MyFormatString::MyFormatString(const char* fmt, va_list varg)
{
    if (fmt)
        mFormatString=fmt;

    va_copy(mVarg, varg);
}
```

Comment: my answer was wrong, Mike's is correct: `va_end()` must be called in the same function which calls `va_copy()`

Comment: I also read the mentioned section from standard C99, 7.15.1.3.

I guess in Solaris this undefined behavior just happens to be that this actually seems to work. 

I guess a safe way would be to pass va_list* -type and use va_copy - va_end in the member funtions? Or pass the va_list to each member funtion...

Answer (score 6):

No, you can only use the `va_list` while the objects it refers to are in scope (in the function itself, or passed as an argument to other functions), up to the point at which you call `va_end`. You *must* call `va_end` before returning from the function and, after that point, the `va_list` is no longer usable.

From C99, 7.15.1.3: "if the `va_end` macro is not invoked before the
return, the behavior is undefined."

In C++11, consider variadic templates or `std::tuple` as type-safe alternatives to old-school variadic functions.

Answer (score 3):

This is not safe on *any* platform; `va_list` points to the stack arguments which will be obsolete when the constructor returns. Consider using a more C++-ish type-safe method to store the arguments; probably storing in a `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work as expected as long as all `MyFormatString` instances are destroyed before the corresponding variadic function returns.

However, it's still undefined behaviour according to the C standard as `va_end()` needs to be called before the function which invoked `va_copy()` returns, though I don't know of any implementations where it doesn't suffice to call `va_end()` before the `va_list` goes out of scope or the corresponding variadic function returns.

If you're looking for a standards-compliant solution, use a `va_list*` instead of a copy of the list. This will share state between `MyFormatString` instances created from the same `va_list`, though, so it is not really equivalent.

If you do not want to share state, you'll need to manually create a copy of the `va_list` and pass a pointer to that to your constructor.

Using pointers [has issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047362/is-gcc-mishandling-a-pointer-to-a-va-list-passed-to-a-function) on platforms where `va_list` is an array type, which can be avoided by using C++ references instead (which obviously aren't accounted for in the C standard, but should behave according to pointer semantics).

Comment: Ok, I was pretty sure it works like that. Is it even portable over different OS's and compilers?