# How is vprintf implemented?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

If one wants to write a function in C that passes a variable argument list through to `printf` one has to use the `vprintf` version. How can I implement this mechanism for a custom function?

In other words, how is the essence of what sets `vprintf` apart from `printf` implemented in standard conforming C?

Comment: Take a look at `<stdarg.h>`.

Comment: [Variadic arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). See also the man page for `va_arg`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to write a function which takes a `va_list` as an argument, the way `vprintf` does, then you just do that. You can extract arguments from the `va_list` with `va_arg` in the normal way.

Don't call `va_start` or `va_end` on the `va_list`: that's the responsibility of the caller. Since you can't restart the `va_list` in the normal way, if you need to scan it more than once, you'll need to `va_copy` it.

Here's a quick example, just for illustration (i.e. it's not meant to be the best possible implementation).

These two functions just join a bunch of strings using a provided delimiter string. The first one is the "v" version (like vsprintf), which implements the logic. The second one is the varargs version which packages up the va_list and passes it to the implementation.

The inner function runs through the arguments twice; the first time it adds the sizes of the strings. Both functions return a newly-malloc'd string which will need to be free'd by the caller.

The argument list must be terminated with a `NULL`.

```
char* vjoin(const char* delim, va_list ap) {
  va_list aq;
  va_copy(aq, ap);
  size_t dlen = strlen(delim);

  /* First pass. Use the copied va_list */
  size_t needed = 1; /* NUL terminator */
  const char* s = va_arg(aq, const char*);
  if (s) {
    needed += strlen(s);
    while ((s = va_arg(aq, const char*)))
      needed += dlen + strlen(s);
  }
  va_end(aq);

  /* Second pass. Use the original va_list */
  char* rv = malloc(needed);
  size_t offset = 0;
  *rv = 0;
  s = va_arg(ap, const char*);
  if (s) {
    strcpy(rv, s);
    offset = strlen(s);
    while ((s = va_arg(ap, const char*))) {
      strcpy(rv + offset, delim);
      strcpy(rv + offset + dlen, s);
      offset += dlen + strlen(s);
    }
  }
  return rv;
}

char* join(const char* delim, ...) {
  va_list ap;
  va_start(ap, delim);
  char* rv = vjoin(delim, ap);
  va_end(ap);
  return rv;
}
```

Comment: I like it, it's the only posts i found which demonistration how to write a
function with va_list argument.

Comment: I thought this was great as first, too - this might be asking for undefined behavior (UB) on 64 bit systems/any systems for which `va_list` is an array type.  
In this case, before any call of `vjoin`, C99 tells us that `ap` will be converted into a `typeof(*ap) *`. `va_copy` expects a `va_list` argument, i.e. an array type.  
Why does this matter here? On function entry, machine code will cause a conversion for each `va_list` argument (i.e. `va_list` (which is an array type) into `typeof(*ap) *`). This conversion yields UB for `ap` inside `vjoin`, since `ap` is `typeof(*ap) *`, already.

Comment: One might be inclined to quickly say "But `vprintf` takes a `va_list` argument, and how else would it work then?". If you try to look into, say the `gcc` implementation though, you will see that `vprintf` isn't written as a C function - it's probably assembler - and is tied in into the entire compiler implementation.

Comment: @polynomial_donut: As far as I know, `vprintf` isn't in `gcc` at all; it's part of `glibc` and there it is definitely written in C: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c;h=ae412e4b8444aea22a691d9f62ecc07cf02a3389;hb=HEAD . The gcc distro includes a version of vprintf in libiberty, but that's also written in C and I don't think it is normally used. If you have some other information, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Ah I was wrong there :) But I also doubt the code breaks down into something like the example you gave here, at least not on x86-64.  
About `va_list` being an array type:  
[see here] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048892/2956948) 
[or here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4958507/2956948).

UB is already possible whenever you call `va_copy` inside `vjoin`, because C99 tells us that on entry into `vjoin`, `ap` is converted into a type `typeof(*ap) *`. Now, any function inside `va_copy` that expects a `va_list` argument and gets `ap` instead, will apply said conversion to `ap` -> UB.

Comment: @polynomial: I think you are missing the fact that C makes it impossible for a function to have an argument which is an array type. See 6.7.6.3 para 7: "A declaration of a parameter as `array of type’` shall be adjusted to `qualified pointer to type`." That precisely matches the decay of the argument array to a pointer to the first element. The fact that a typedef is used changes nothing. Your first link is not relevant to my code since I don't attempt to pass by reference.

Comment: @polynomial: as for your doubt, perhaps it would be assauged by an inspection of the actual implementation of `fprintf` in terms of `vfprintf` in glibc: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/fprintf.c;h=2bbf14bf5d177881d0437ef5bb91aded63bcb98d;hb=HEAD Anyway, the C standard makes it pretty clear that the usage in my example is legit: "If access to the varying arguments is desired, the called function shall declare an object (generally referred to as ap in this subclause) having type va_list. The object ap may be passed as an argument to another function;" (7.16p).

Answer (score 2):

The big difference is, of course, that `printf` takes a variable number of optional arguments after the format string, while `vprintf` takes a single non-optional argument that "points" to all arguments.

Most implementations of `printf` creates this single data structure and in turn calls `vprintf`.

Read any tutorial about variable number of arguments (also known as variadic arguments) to see how it works. [This `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might also come in handy, as well as [this variable arguments reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) (which has an example).

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to realize that `vprintf` (or more likely `vfprintf`) is the underlying core function that's implemented. `printf` is likely to be just a wrapper that calls `va_start`, `vprintf`, then `va_end`.