# Passing variadic parameters from one function to another

Tags: c++, parameters, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

I am calling a function `firstFunction` and passing it variadic arguments  `(const char* fmt, ...)` : I would like to execute some calculations here and then pass the parameters to another function, `secondFunction` that has  `(const char* fmt, ...)` as input arguments.

```
void firstFunction(const char* fmt, ...)
{
 //does some pre-condition stuff

//calls secondFunction (how?)
}

void secondFunction(const char* fmt, ...)
{
//prints the input parameters in a va_list using vsnprtinf
}
```

What is the C++ syntax to pass variadic arguments from a function to another?

EDIT 1: I can't use templates, since I would like these functions to be a definition of pure virtual functions declaration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36881533/passing-va-list-to-other-functions

Comment: Note: a *parameter pack* only occurs in variadic templates, this is a C-style varags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a variadic paramater, not a parameter pack. In c++ you would write:

```
    template <class... Args>
    void firstFunction(const char* fmt, Args&&... a) {
        secondFunction(fmt, std::forward<Args>(a)...);
    }
```

Comment: You're right, question corrected