# What is the cross-platform way to pass a va_list by reference?

Tags: c

I wrote a function that accepts a `va_list`, and that is meant to be invoked iteratively by its caller. It should modify the `va_list` and changes should persist back in the caller so that the next call to the function will proceed with the next argument.

I can't post that code specifically, but here's a snippet that reproduces the situation ([godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/grnTA7)):

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_integer(va_list ap) {
    printf("%i\n", va_arg(ap, int));
}

void vprint_integers(int count, va_list ap) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        print_integer(ap);
    }
}

void print_integers(int count, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, count);
    vprint_integers(count, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main() {
    print_integers(3, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

This works (prints "1 2 3") on my x86 platform because `va_list` is passed by "reference" (it's probably declared as an array of one element, so `va_list` arguments decay to a pointer). However, it does *not* work on my ARM platform (prints "1 1 1"), where `va_list` seems to be defined as a pointer to something. On that platform, `va_arg` always returns the first argument.

The next best option seems to be to make `ap` a pointer:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_integer(va_list *ap) {
    printf("%i\n", va_arg(*ap, int));
}

void vprint_integers(int count, va_list ap) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        print_integer(&ap);
    }
}

void print_integers(int count, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, count);
    vprint_integers(count, ap);
    va_end(ap);
}

int main() {
    print_integers(3, 1, 2, 3);
}
```

This works on ARM (with `va_arg(*ap, ...)`), but it does not compile on x86. When I try `print_integer(&ap)` on x86, Clang says:

> error: incompatible pointer types passing '`struct __va_list_tag **`' to parameter of type '`va_list *`' (aka '`__builtin_va_list *`')

This only seems to happen when taking the address of a `va_list` passed as an argument, not when it's taken from a local variable. Unfortunately, I do need my `v` variant to take a `va_list` object and not a pointer to it.

It's easy to get consistent cross-platform value semantics for `va_list` using `va_copy`. Is there a cross-platform way to get consistent reference semantics for `va_list`?

Comment: Can we see `va_do_stuff`? How you're using `va_list` is probably important.

Comment: @Schwern, you unfortunately can't. [Here's an example](https://godbolt.org/z/dTEoaC) if this helps you understand what I'm talking about: it prints "1 2 3" on x86 and "1 1 1" on ARM, and my goal is to pass the va_list in a way that it prints "1 2 3" on ARM too. Aside from that, I don't know what `va_do_stuff` could help you more with to answer this question.

Comment: @zneak That should be included in the question, as well as the version using `va_list *ap`

Comment: @zneak We don't need to see the original, just a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which demonstrates the problem. Your example helps, but we also need to see how you're modifying `va_list`.

Comment: The question has been updated.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047362/is-gcc-mishandling-a-pointer-to-a-va-list-passed-to-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing at issue here is that `va_list`, on the x86 platform, is defined as an array of 1 element (let's call it `__va_list_tag[1]`). It decays to a pointer when accepted as an argument, so `&ap` is wildly different depending on whether `ap` is a parameter of the function (`__va_list_tag**`) or a local variable (`__va_list_tag(*)[1]`).

One solution that works for this case is simply to create a local `va_list`, use `va_copy` to populate it, and pass a pointer to this local `va_list`. ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/g_5MVW))

```
void vprint_integers(int count, va_list ap) {
    va_list local;
    va_copy(local, ap);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        print_integer(&local);
    }
    va_end(local);
}
```

In my case, `vprint_integers` and `va_copy` are necessary because the interface of `vprint_integers` accepts a `va_list` and that cannot change. With more flexible requirements, changing `vprint_integers` to accept a `va_list` pointer is fine too.

`va_list` isn't specified to be anything in particular, but it's defined to be an object type, so there's not really a reason to believe that you can't take or pass its address. Another very similar solution that entirely bypasses the question of whether you can take the address of a `va_list` is to wrap the `va_list` in a struct and pass a pointer to that struct.

Answer (score 0):

You may be out of luck. 7.15(3) says what you're doing has indeterminate effects.

> The  object `ap` may  be  passed  as  an  argument  to another  function;  if  that  function  invokes  the `va_arg` macro  with  parameter `ap`,  the value  of `ap` in  the  calling  function  is  indeterminate  and  shall  be  passed  to  the `va_end` macro prior to any further reference to `ap`.

The call to `va_arg` in `print_integer` is causing `ap` in `print_integers` to be indeterminate. On one architecture it's being incremented, on another it isn't.

As for what `va_list` is, it could be anything...

> ...which   is   an   object   type   suitable   for   holding   information   needed   by   the   macros va_start, va_arg, va_end, and va_copy.

[You may wish to consider a different approach to solving the underlying problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: One thing I don't like about x-y problems is that there seems to be an assumption that OP doesn't actually know what their problem is. Asking for a minimum repro case is an excellent step that I did not spend enough time on. On the other hand, I believe that for most people who are writing code professionally, telling other people "you can't do that" is usually perceived as more respectful of their abilities than telling them "I could help *if only you told me more about your requirements*". My requirements are old enough to drink.

Comment: `ap` in `print_integers` is not used after being made indeterminate, so there is no problem in that regard. It is a common pattern to pass `va_list` "by value" (as such) to a function, and of course not continue to use it in the calling context.

Comment: @zneak A professional does not take it personally when asked to consider an oblique solution to a hard problem. If it's not an XY Problem they say "this is not an XY Problem", or  they say nothing at all. I hope you solve your problem.

Comment: @Schwern, if my comment rubbed you the wrong way, consider asking yourself why you feel that I am not justified to criticize your communications whereas you find yourself justified to criticize mine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the second program is that if `va_list` is an array type, then the function parameter `ap` has its type *adjusted* to be a pointer type.  So the argument has a different level of indirection in each case.

Since C11 we can solve this with a generic selector to test whether or not `ap` is still a `va_list`:

```
void vprint_integers(int count, va_list ap) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        print_integer((va_list *)_Generic(&ap, va_list*: &ap, default: ap));
    }
```

This solution was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8048892/1505939) which used a macro for the two cases that required manual configuration .

Notes about the `_Generic`:

- We have to test `&ap` because, since C18, array-to-pointer decay is performed on the first expression.
- Originally I had `_Generic(&ap, va_list*: &ap, default: (va_list *)ap)` however this is rejected by compilers which check for constraint violations in all branches for all inputs -- although do not go on to check constraint violations in the surrounding expressions for unselected branches.

Comment: This doesn't build on some x86 platforms (notably mine and the one that runs [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EqVXXe)). It's the first thing that I tried.

Comment: @zneak oh, the problem is that function parameter `ap` no longer has the type `va_list` due to adjustment. I'll revise my answer

Comment: I posted what you're probably about to post a few minutes ago. :)

Comment: @zneak I had something else in mind, there is more than one way to skin a cat :)

Comment: @zneak my answer is now either genius or horrible, can you test it on your platform?

Comment: This would work for all the ABIs that Clang supports, I believe. On the other hand, I do like the certainty of where reference semantics start and end with the va_copy approach.

Comment: @zneak OK. I managed to fix the original problem in my answer with constraint violation