# Is returning va_list safe in C?

Tags: c, c99, c89, variadic-functions

I'd like to write a function that has return type of va_list.

example: `va_list MyFunc(va_list args);`

is this safe and portable?

Comment: If your intent is to pass in a `va_list`, modify it, then use that modified `va_list` upon return from the function, it might be better to consider passing  a pointer to a `va_list` to `MyFunct()` and have it act on the list via the pointer.  The standard specifically mentions that technique being permissible in a footnote.

Comment: this is exactly my intention. Could you point where in standard it is permitted?

Comment: In my opinion, `va_list` are a bad idea. There are usually better solutions that are more safe. So I would have a hard think and get a better solution to the design and implementation of the function.

Comment: @Michael Burr i saw an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369588/pass-va-list-or-pointer-to-va-list) and I think the footnote:

215) It is permitted to create a pointer to a va_list and pass that pointer to another function, in which case the original function may make further use of the original list after the other function returns

Comment: Passing a pointer to another function is quite different from returning that pointer though. Many/most implementations store the actual variable arguments in a stack frame that is destroyed when the vararg function returns. (i.e. returning a va_list or a pointer to one, will leave you with pointers to local variables that's destroyed).

Comment: well in my case i'd be returning va_list back but thanks for warning

Comment: @Ali Veli Like I explained, returning a va_list makes little sense. Don't do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`va_list` *might* (but is not guaranteed to) be an array type, so you can't pass or return it by value. Code that looks as if it does, might just be passing/returning a pointer to the first element, so you can use the parameter in the callee but you might be acting on the original.

Formally you can probably say that `va_list` is an entity type, not a value type. You copy it with `va_copy`, not with assignment or via function parameters/return.

Answer (score 1):

While you can definitely `return` such a value, I am not sure if the return value can be used in a useful way.

As the handling of `va_list`s requires special treatment (`va_end()` required after `va_start()` and `va_copy()`), and `va_start/copy` and `va_end` macros are even allowed to contain `{ }` to enforce this pairing, you cannot call one without the other.

Comment: `va_copy` is used to create a *second* `va_list` object that could be read independently of the original one. As this is not the case here, I would say that it is OK to pass and return the `va_list` object. Also, the standard does not mention that `va_start()` and `va_end()` must be in the same scope, hence I don't see how they could be allowed to contain `{`:es.

Comment: @Lindydancer Oh, didn't know about that. [Here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_start) I read "Each invocation of va_start() must be matched by a corresponding invocation of va_end() in the same function" and "Each invocation of va_copy() must be matched by a corresponding invocation of va_end() in the same function.", so I thought it cones from the standard...

Comment: @glglgl: "in the same function" doesn't necessarily mean "in the same scope", so doesn't imply that the macros can use unmatched braces. But it does allow `va_copy` to use tricks like `alloca`, since the new list doesn't live beyond function return.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the language standard says, this is unlikely to work in practice. A `va_list` is likely to be a pointer to a call record placed on the stack by a caller for the benefit of the callee. Once the callee returns, that memory on the stack is fair game for reuse.

Returning the type `va_list` is unlikely to actually copy the content of the list back to the caller. Although that would be a valid implementation of C, if the standard requires it be done so, that would be a defect in the specification.

Comment: The reason why the `va_end` macro exists is exactly because the `va_list` is not necessarily just a pointer to something on the stack.  Otherwise, `va_end` would always be a no-op.  There exist implementations where `va_list` objects are allocated on the heap.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Good info, I thought `va_end` had something to do with register windows or old implementations that only allowed one iterator at a time. Adjusted my answer, but it's just a matter of relative emphasis… most architectures don't use the heap for varargs.

Answer (score 1):

> Passing a pointer to another function is quite different from
>   returning that pointer though. Many/most implementations store the
>   actual variable arguments in a stack frame that is destroyed when the
>   vararg function returns. (i.e. returning a va_list or a pointer to
>   one, will leave you with pointers to local variables that's
>   destroyed). – nos
>
> well in my case i'd be returning va_list back but thanks for warning –
>   Hayri Uğur Koltuk

If you pass a pointer to a `va_list` to the function `MyFunc(va_list *args)`, you don't need to pass the modified (by `va_arg(*args, type)`) argument list back, since `MyFunc` modifies the original list.

Comment: I don't think it's specified whether `MyFunc` modifies the original list.  I've certainly encountered implementations that work both ways.

Comment: @supercat - If a pointer to any object is passed to a function, and the function modifies the pointed-to object, it is inherent that the original object is modified.

Comment: If a va_list is a simple pointer (as would be most efficient on many platforms), passing it to a function would give a function a copy of the pointer, and va_arg would increment that copy of the pointer without affecting the original.

Comment: @supercat - We (possibly except you) are talking about passing _a pointer to a `va_list` to the function_, so also _If a va_list is a simple pointer_, _a pointer to_ that pointer _is passed_, and _the function modifies the pointed-to_ original pointer.

Comment: Okay, I see where I was confused.  I've gotten bitten by the fact that on some systems a `va_list` is an array, an argument of that type *inherently* gets passed as a pointer, whereas on other systems it does not, but I now see that in your particular case you're including the `*` in the argument type so it will be passed as a single-indirect pointer (to whatever is in the `va_list`, which likely contains another pointer) regardless.