# Put a va_list variable inside... a variable argument list (!)

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I would like to design a function which takes a variable number of arguments, one of these arguments being itself a `va_list`; but something gets wrong in my code and I do not understand what...

**WARNING — My question is not about designing a code doing what I wish to do (I have found a way to bypass the problem), but only about understanding what I did wrong...**

To explain my question, let us start with a simple example: namely, a function `ffprintf` which acts like `fprintf`, but writing its contents onto several strings, strings whose number is indicated by the first argument of `ffprintf`, and whose identities are given by the very next arguments (the number of these arguments may vary from one call to another, so you have to use a variable argument list). Such a function would be used like this:

```
FILE *stream0, *stream1, *stream2;
int a, b;
ffprintf (3, stream0, stream1, stream2, "%d divided by %d worths %f", a, b, (double)a / b);
```

And its code would be:

```
void ffprintf (int z, ...)
 {va_list vlist, auxvlist;
  FILE **streams = malloc (z * sizeof(FILE *));
  va_start (vlist, z);
  for (int i = 0; i < z; ++i)
   {streams[i] = va_arg (vlist, FILE *); // Getting the next stream argument
   }
  char const *format = va_arg (vlist, char const *); // Getting the format argument
  for (int i = 0; i < z; ++i)
   {va_copy (auxvlist, vlist); // You have to work on a copy "auxvlist" of "vlist", for otherwise "vlist" would be altered by the next line
    vfprintf (streams[i], format, auxvlist);
    va_end (auxvlist);
   }
  va_end (vlist);
  free (streams);
 }
```

That works fine. Now, there is also the standard function `vfprintf`, whose prototype is `vfprintf (FILE *stream, char const* format, va_list vlist);`, and which you use like this to create another function having a variable argument list:

```
void fprintf_variant (FILE *stream, char const* format, ...)
 {
  va_list vlist;
  va_start (vlist, format);
  vfprintf (stream, format, vlist);
  va_end (vlist);
 }
```

That works fine too. Now, my goal is to combine both ideas to create a function which I would call `vffprintf`, which you would use like this:

```
FILE *stream0, *stream1, *stream2;
void fprintf_onto_streams012 (char const *format, ...)
 {va_list vlist;
  va_start (vlist, format);
  vffprintf (3, stream0, stream1, stream2, format, vlist);
  va_end (vlist);
 }
```

I have designed the following code:

```
void vffprintf (int z, ...)
 {va_list vlist, auxvlist, auxauxvlist;
  va_start (vlist, z);
  FILE **streams = malloc (z * sizeof(FILE *));
  for (int i = 0; i < z; ++i)
   {streams[i] = va_arg (vlist, FILE *);
   }
  char const *format = va_arg (vlist, char const *);
  va_copy (auxvlist, va_arg (vlist, va_list)); // Here I get the next argument of "vlist", knowing that this argument is of "va_list" type
  for (int i = 0; i < z; ++i)
   {va_copy (auxauxvlist, auxvlist);
    vfprintf (streams[i], format, auxvlist);
    va_end (auxauxvlist);
   }
  va_end (auxvlist);
  va_end (vlist);
  free (streams);
 }
```

This code compiles without a hitch, but it does not work properly... For instance, if I write the following complete code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void vffprintf (int z, ...)
 {va_list vlist, auxvlist, auxauxvlist;
  FILE **streams = malloc (z * sizeof(FILE *));
  va_start (vlist, z);
  for (int i = 0; i < z; ++i)
   {streams[i] = va_arg (vlist, FILE *);
   }
  char const *format = va_arg (vlist, char const *);
  va_copy (auxvlist, va_arg (vlist, va_list));
  for (int i = 0; i < z; ++i)
   {va_copy (auxauxvlist, auxvlist);
    vfprintf (streams[i], format, auxauxvlist);
    va_end (auxauxvlist);
   }
  va_end (auxvlist);
  va_end (vlist);
  free (streams);
 }

void printf_variant (char const *format, ...)
 {va_list vlist;
  va_start (vlist, format);
  vffprintf (1, stdout, format, vlist);
  va_end (vlist);
 }

int main (void)
 {printf_variant ("Ramanujan's number is %d.\n", 1729);
  return 0;
 }
```

I get a segfault!... Why?!

P.-S.: Sorry for that very long question; but I wanted it to be perfectly clear, for it is rather technical...

P.-S.2: I used deliberately both tags "va-list" and "variableargumentlists" for this question, because which interests me is `va_list`, *seen as a type*, inside a (other) variable argument list, *seen as a list*... So these are really two different concepts here.

Comment: So the question is why is the last example failing?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly that :-)

Comment: Looks fine if you ignore the memory leak.

Comment: `FILE **streams = malloc (z * sizeof(FILE *));`

Comment: Oops! I do not even know how I could commit such a blunder... :-S Corrected it.

Comment: You might( read: must ) also want to start checking the return values from the library function.

Comment: Oh, you were meaning, I did not check whether memory allocation succeeded? Actually I was aware of not having done it; but I wanted to focus on my main problem, so here let us assume that everything gets fine.

Comment: Can I confirm one point.  `ffprintf (N, stream0, stream1.. streamN, formatter1, arg1,arg2,arg3...argM)`; So my question is here you want to design is only one formatter(formatter1) or a few formatter(formatter1...formatterN)?

Comment: One formatter only actually.

Comment: OK. got it.Now I know the aim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The description of `va_arg` in the final draft of C11 (N1570) contains (*type* is the second argument):

> if *type* is not compatible with the *type* of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined

`va_list` is allowed to be an array type (the standard requires it to be a so-called “complete object type”) and it seems your implementation makes use of this possibility. You probably know that in C arrays can't be passed as arguments as they decay into pointers, and the type of such a pointer isn't compatible with the original array type.

For example: `int *` isn't compatible with `int [1]`. So if you really need to pass an array or a `va_list` portably, then define a `struct` with a `va_list` member and pass that (see [Why can't we pass arrays to function by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454990/why-cant-we-pass-arrays-to-function-by-value)).

Comment: Hello cremno,

I have not grasped all the details, but I have the impression that your point is linked to the following clause from the standard: “The argument `type` is a type name specified so that the type of a pointer to an object that has the specified type can be obtained simply by adding a `*` to `type`”. But nothing guarantees that `va_list` would be such a type, as e.g. an array type would not work... Is it correct?

On the other hand, this does not seem to explain how the “void*” trick of Eric Tsui worked...

Comment: @Nancy-N: It's a **trick**. But he has to explain that one as that's part of his answer. It'll probably work everywhere you'll ever care about. THat doesn't change the fact it's UB (the description posted by him is also erroneous). [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50581)'s a GCC bug report, whose reporter wants to do something similar or even the same as you. It even mentions an edge case in C90! Maybe reading it will clear things a bit more up than my answer. It also mentions using a structure as a possible solution.

Comment: @cremno, thanks for the correction.  So, I did more studies for things about `va_list` and `va_list*` under different `va_list` implementation, that's indeed the problem.

Comment: @cremno: Thanks for this further explanation. Thanks to it and to Eric Tsui's posts, now I do understand what went wrong.

Comment: @cremno I'm not sure it is correct to wrap a `va_list` in a struct and pass it to a function. As you say, it may be an array type and so it is implicitly passed by reference; whereas the struct wrap option will make a byte-wise copy. `va_copy` is supposed to be used any time that a `va_list` should be copied, so this could trash the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
void vffprintf (int z, ...)
 {
  //...
  va_copy (auxvlist, va_arg (vlist, va_list));//this line has the problem 
   //...
 }
```

Just a quick and tricky way like this, it will work.

```
  void vffprintf (int z, ...)
 {
  //...
  va_copy (auxvlist, va_arg (vlist, void*));
   //...
 }
```

Here are some references about `var_arg` and `va_list`, which should have provided detailed and thorough explanation.

1) [Pass va_list or pointer to va_list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369588/pass-va-list-or-pointer-to-va-list)

2) [Is GCC mishandling a pointer to a va_list passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047362/is-gcc-mishandling-a-pointer-to-a-va-list-passed-to-a-function)

3) [What is the format of the x86_64 va_list structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958384/what-is-the-format-of-the-x86-64-va-list-structure/4958507#4958507)

Hope they are helpful.

Comment: That works indeed; terrific! :-D If you have any more detailed explanation, I am much eager to hear it: Why did the previous line fail? Why does the new one work? It this “void* trick” portable?...

Comment: It remains unclear to me. When `printf_variant` calls `vffprintf`, the variable argument list for `vffprintf` is {`stdout`, `format`, `vlist_0`}, with `vlist_0` being the variable arguments list of `printf_variant`, namely {`1929`}. So, when calling `va_arg (vlist_1, va_list)` (I have put suffixes `_0` and `_1` to make the difference between both `vlist` clear), the next argument of `vlist_1` is {`1929`}, which concretely may be a `struct {char *, int}`. But this is not an int, is it ?... And anyway, how might that be converted to a `void *`?!

Sorry for not understanding more easily...

Comment: @Nancy-N, what I tried to do is something like this `va_copy (auxvlist, va_arg (vlist, va_list*))`, but it gives the warning. So, I change it to ``va_copy (auxvlist, va_arg (vlist, void*))``

Comment: @Nancy-N Thanks. I also learned more from the question. And I posted several helpful references which I studied, especially the 2nd link [Is GCC mishandling a pointer to a va_list passed to a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047362/is-gcc-mishandling-a-pointer-to-a-va-list-passed-to-a-function)

Comment: @ Eric Tsui - Thank you for your complementary explanations and your references; now I think I have got it.

Comment: @ Eric Tsui: I have marked cremno's answer as accepted rather than yours, as cremno's answer directly stresses out the key point; but your posts were at least as helpful to me as cremno's for my understanding!

Comment: @Nancy-N: I agree with you :) This question itself is quite good and involves  many underneath mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to wrap the type va_list into a struct, if you want to retrieve it using va_arg():

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef struct
{
    va_list list ;  
} my_list ;

void vffprintf (int z, ...)
 {my_list vlist, auxvlist, auxauxvlist;
  FILE **streams = malloc (z * sizeof(FILE *));
  va_start (vlist.list, z);
  for (int i = 0; i < z; ++i)
   {streams[i] = va_arg (vlist.list, FILE *);
   }
  char const *format = va_arg (vlist.list, char const *);
  my_list parent = va_arg (vlist.list, my_list) ;
  va_copy (auxvlist.list, parent.list );
  for (int i = 0; i < z; ++i)
   {va_copy (auxauxvlist.list, auxvlist.list);
    vfprintf (streams[i], format, auxauxvlist.list);
    va_end (auxauxvlist.list);
   }
  va_end (auxvlist.list);
  va_end (vlist.list);
  free (streams);
 }

void printf_variant (char const *format, ...)
 {my_list vlist;
  va_start (vlist.list, format);
  vffprintf (1, stdout , format, vlist);
  va_end (vlist.list);
 }

int main (void)
 {printf_variant ("Ramanujan's number is %d.\n", 1729 );
  return 0;
 }
```

The problem stems from the fact that array and a pointer of the same type are not compatible, and va_list is defined as an array. Then you try to get that type:

```
va_arg (vlist, va_list)
```

So you tell `va_arg` you are getting an array but if fact the passed `va_list` has decayed to a pointer. You should use the pointer version of `va_list`, but you don't know the real definition of `va_list`, in the first place so you cannot obtain the pointer version of it.

The solution is to wrap `va_list` into a type you control, a struct.

Comment: @ this - Thank you for this way of bypassing the problem (which I did not know) and for having written down the code! :-)

Comment: @Nancy-N So did this code actually fix the problem?

Comment: @ this - It did indeed — at least on my own machine ;-)