# Unexpected behavior of va_list when used in multiple functions

Tags: c++, c

In my project I'm making a C class hierarchy similar to, but not the same as Axel-Tobias Schreiner Object-oriented Programming in ansi C see https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf. for example.

I'm initializing my object a little bit different than Axel is. I'm running into troubles when I'm passing va_list objects between multiple initializing functions. Say I've an object **two**, that derives from object **one**. Then while initializing a **two** object, I'll need to initialize the **one** part first, and subsequently initialize the **two** part.
So I'm having 1 init function that calls the public initializer function with arguments that initialize the **one** part of the **two** object and arguments that only initializes the **two** part that extends **one** object.

The library I'm creating is quite large, but I've extracted a mini project from it that demonstrates the same issues:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project (var_args
        VERSION     "0.0"
        LANGUAGES   C CXX
        )

set(HEADERS "init.h")
set(SOURCES init.c program.c)

add_executable(program ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS})

if (NOT MSVC)
    target_compile_options(program PRIVATE -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic)
else()
    target_compile_options(program PRIVATE /W4)
endif()
```

init.h:

```
typedef struct _one {
    int a;
    const char* msg;
} one_t;

/* this struct "derives" from struct _one */
typedef struct _two {
    one_t   parent;
    double  pi;
    double  e;
}two_t;

enum status_t {
    STATUS_SUCCES,
    STATUS_INVALID_ARGUMENT,
    STATUS_ERROR
};

enum init_one_flags {
    INIT_ONE_A,         // 2nd argument should be of type int
    INIT_ONE_MSG,       // 3rd argument should be const char*
    INIT_ONE_FINISHED,  // takes no arugment, but rather tell init1 should be finished.
    INIT_ONE_SENTINAL   // Keep at the last position.
};

enum init_two_flags {
    INIT_TWO_PI = INIT_ONE_SENTINAL,    // 2nd arugument should be of type double.
    INIT_TWO_E,                         // 2nd argument shoudl be double.
    INIT_TWO_FINISHED,                  // takes no arugment, but rather tell init2 should be finished.
    INIT_TWO_SENTINAL,                  // for init3...
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int init_two(two_t* two, ...);

//void init_one(one_t* one, ...);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

init.c:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include "init.h"

static int priv_init1(one_t* one, va_list list)
{
    // use default values;
    int a = 0;
    const char* msg = "";

    int selector, ret = STATUS_SUCCES;

    while ((selector = va_arg(list, int)) != INIT_ONE_FINISHED) {
        switch (selector) {
        case INIT_ONE_A:
            a = va_arg(list, int);
            break;
        case INIT_ONE_MSG:
            msg = va_arg(list, const char*);
            break;
        default:
            // unknown argument
            return STATUS_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }
    }

    one->a = a;
    one->msg = msg;
    return ret;
}

static int priv_init2(two_t* two, va_list list)
{
    double pi = 3.1415, e=2.7128;
    int selector, ret = STATUS_SUCCES;

    ret = priv_init1((one_t*)two, list);
    if (ret)
        return ret;

    while ((selector = va_arg(list, int)) != INIT_TWO_FINISHED) {
        switch (selector) {
        case INIT_TWO_PI:
            pi = va_arg(list, double);
            break;
        case INIT_TWO_E:
            pi = va_arg(list, double);
            break;
        default:
            return STATUS_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }
    }

    two->pi = pi;
    two->e = e;

    return STATUS_SUCCES;
}

int init_two(two_t* two, ...)
{
    int ret;
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, two);
    ret = priv_init2(two, list);
    va_end(list);

    return ret;
}
```

program.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "init.h"

int main() {
    int ret;
    two_t two;

    ret = init_two(
        &two,
        INIT_ONE_A,         1,
        INIT_ONE_MSG,       "Hello, world",
        INIT_ONE_FINISHED,
        INIT_TWO_PI,        2 * 3.1415,
        INIT_TWO_FINISHED
    );

    if (ret) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to init two...\n");
        printf("a=%d\tmsg=%s\tpi=%lf\te%lf\n",
            two.parent.a,
            two.parent.msg,
            two.pi,
            two.e
        );
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("a=%d\tmsg=%s\tpi=%lf\te%lf\n",
            two.parent.a,
            two.parent.msg,
            two.pi,
            two.e
        );
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now the problem I'm running into is that the behavior of this code is exactly what I expect on Linux with gcc or clang in debug and release builds. Unfortunately the code fails on Windows with visual studio 17.

So the output of the program should be someting like:

> a=1   msg=Hello, world    pi=6.283000 e2.712800

And that is exactly what I obtain on Linux with gcc (5.4.0-6)

On windows I get:

> a=1   msg=Hello, world    pi=jiberish here e2=jiberish here.

And the function `init_two` does return that the function was successful on Linux and that is is not successful on windows. Also I can see that the part of one_t part of two is initialized successfully, whereas the two_t part is not.
I would be very grateful if someone would point out the issue what is going wrong. Is the va_list is passed by reference on Linux, whereas the va_list is passed by value on windows? Are the enum values promoted to int on Linux, whereas they are passed as char on windows?
Finally, I tagged the question as C and C++ because I know the code I demonstrate is C, but I would like it to work with a C++ compiler as well.

Comment: you should use va_copy() if you want to use an argument list twice. Not sure if it exists in windows, though

Comment: @Ingo The point is, I don't want it copied, that is where I think my bug is. The function that initializes the one_t part of two_t should (at least that is what I hope) "consume" the arguments relevant to one_t so that the while loop in `priv_init21 only sees the arguments relevant to the two_t. But perhaps that is where my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: I see.. Unfortunately I can't think of a portable way to achieve that. The implementations of the va_..() macros differ a lot between platforms

Comment: Once one function has modified the argument list, you cannot reliably pass it to another.

Comment: Hmm, @JonathanLeffler, the standard seems to put it exactly the opposite way: if you pass a `va_list` to another function and that function uses `va_arg` on it, its value in the *calling* function becomes indeterminate.  I'm having trouble finding a similar specification of the reverse.

Comment: @JohnBollinger — I was trying to say what you said better.  Put it down to lack of caffeine.

Comment: IMO problem is that you are assuming that `priv_init1` will change value of `list` inside of `priv_init2`. This is not defined behavior so you can't assume that. In fact I'm surprised that it worked for gcc. Apparently on gcc va_start creates local varaible and `va_arg` is just a pointer to that variable. In case of VS `va_arg` is an variable and `va_start` just initialize that.

Comment: @MarekR and clang, but it doesn't work for msvc. So I must, probably take a step back and figure out a better way to chain my inializer function to the parent. would you or anyone have an idea?

Comment: clang was design to be compatible with gcc. I would say VS behavior is what I would expected. Anyway your requirement is strange, its looks like XY Problem, so maybe you should explain why you need this behavior?

Comment: A quick fix would be pass `va_list` by pointer not by value than it will work on any compiler.

Comment: @Mareks idea seems to be covered by the the standard as quoted in the accepted answer of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369588/pass-va-list-or-pointer-to-va-list)

Comment: You are not calling `va_start` nor `va_end` - why not? Those are *mandatory*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I am calling va_start and end in `init_two()`. Things go to oblivion at the moment I mistakenly thought that I could pass it from `priv_init2` to `priv_init1`, use it in `priv_init1` and after `priv_init1` returns use it again in `priv_init2`. But the answers below and the comments are very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of `va_list` can differ greatly across compilers.

It's possible, for example, that gcc implements it as a pointer so passing it to another function by value still modifies the underlying structure so that changes in the called function are visible in the calling function, while MSVC implements it as a struct so changes in the calling function are *not* visible in the caller.

You can get around this by passing a pointer to your initial `va_list` instance to all the functions that need it.  Then the internal state will be consistent in all functions.

```
// use pointer to va_list
static int priv_init1(one_t* one, va_list *list)
{
    // use default values;
    int a = 0;
    const char* msg = "";

    int selector, ret = STATUS_SUCCES;

    while ((selector = va_arg(*list, int)) != INIT_ONE_FINISHED) {
        switch (selector) {
        case INIT_ONE_A:
            a = va_arg(*list, int);
            break;
        case INIT_ONE_MSG:
            msg = va_arg(*list, const char*);
            break;
        default:
            // unknown argument
            return STATUS_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }
    }

    one->a = a;
    one->msg = msg;

    return ret;
}

// use pointer to va_list
static int priv_init2(two_t* two, va_list *list)
{
    double pi = 3.1415, e=2.7128;
    int selector, ret = STATUS_SUCCES;

    ret = priv_init1((one_t*)two, list);
    if (ret)
        return ret;

    while ((selector = va_arg(*list, int)) != INIT_TWO_FINISHED) {
        switch (selector) {
        case INIT_TWO_PI:
            pi = va_arg(*list, double);
            break;
        case INIT_TWO_E:
            pi = va_arg(*list, double);
            break;
        default:
            return STATUS_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }
    }

    two->pi = pi;
    two->e = e;

    return STATUS_SUCCES;
}

int init_two(two_t* two, ...)
{
    int ret;
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, two);
    ret = priv_init2(two, &list);    // pass pointer
    va_end(list);

    return ret;
}
```

This usage is explicitly mentioned in section 7.16p3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The type declared is
>
> ```
> va_list
> ```
>
> which  is  a  complete  object  type  suitable  for  holding 
>   information  needed  by  the  macros `va_start` , `va_arg` , `va_end` ,  and
>   `va_copy` .  If  access  to  the  varying  arguments  is desired,  the 
>   called  function  shall  declare  an  object  (generally  referred  to
>   as `ap` in  this subclause)  having  type `va_list`. 
>   The  object `ap` may  be  passed  as  an  argument  to another 
>   function;  if  that  function  invokes  the `va_arg` macro  with 
>   parameter `ap` ,  the value  of `ap` in  the  calling  function  is 
>   indeterminate  and  shall  be  passed  to  the `va_end` macro prior to
>   any further reference to `ap`. <sup>253)</sup>
>
> 253) **It  is  permitted  to  create  a  pointer  to  a `va_list` and 
>   pass  that  pointer  to  another  function,  in  which case the
>   original function may make further use of the original list after the
>   other function returns.**

Answer (score 3):

This should work with any compiler:

```
static int priv_init1(one_t* one, va_list* list)
{
    // use default values;
    int a = 0;
    const char* msg = "";

    int selector, ret = STATUS_SUCCES;

    while ((selector = va_arg(*list, int)) != INIT_ONE_FINISHED) {
        switch (selector) {
        case INIT_ONE_A:
            a = va_arg(*list, int);
            break;
        case INIT_ONE_MSG:
            msg = va_arg(*list, const char*);
            break;
        default:
            // unknown argument
            return STATUS_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }
    }

    one->a = a;
    one->msg = msg;
    return ret;
}

static int priv_init2(two_t* two, va_list list)
{
    double pi = 3.1415, e=2.7128;
    int selector, ret = STATUS_SUCCES;

    ret = priv_init1((one_t*)two, &list);
    if (ret)
        return ret;

    while ((selector = va_arg(list, int)) != INIT_TWO_FINISHED) {
        switch (selector) {
        case INIT_TWO_PI:
            pi = va_arg(list, double);
            break;
        case INIT_TWO_E:
            pi = va_arg(list, double);
            break;
        default:
            return STATUS_INVALID_ARGUMENT;
        }
    }

    two->pi = pi;
    two->e = e;

    return STATUS_SUCCES;
}
```

Anyway your design that `va_list` is increased by two diffrent functions looks very fragile. I wouldn't do that.

Also you API design requires specific and complex sequnce of arguments which compilers do not recognize. This is so bug prone that I would not pass this in code review.

Since this looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I recommend creating another question about your X problem (how to design API which does what you need).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the issue revolves around the fact that your implementation of inheritance requires the initialization function for a subclass to call the initialization function(s) of its superclass(es).  This is combined with the fact that the user-facing initialization functions are declared as varargs functions.  To make this work, the varargs functions serve as front ends for internal functions that accept the variable arguments via single parameters of type `va_list`.

This can be made to work in standard C, but you must observe some restrictions.  Among those:

- Your varargs functions must each initialize their `va_list` via the `va_start` macro, exactly once.
- Your functions may pass objects of type `va_list` to other functions, but the caller may not afterward use that object unless they can be confident that the called function did not use either `va_arg` nor `va_end` on it, or unless they themselves first use `va_end` and then `va_start` on it.
- Every use of `va_start` or `va_copy` must be paired with a corresponding use of `va_end` on the same `va_list`
- Of course, it is up to you to ensure that the correct data types are specified to each use of `va_arg`.

You violate the second requirement by passing a `va_list` from one internal initialization function to another, and then afterward using it.

You should be able to work around this by passing *pointers* to the `va_list` and accessing it indirectly, so that all the functions involved use the same object.  This will enable the state of the `va_list` to be shared, so that, for example, the initialization function for the topmost class can effectively consume the arguments intended for it, without its subclasses needing to know their number or types.  That would take a form something like this:

```
static int priv_init1(one_t* one, va_list *list) {
    while ((selector = va_arg((*list), int)) != INIT_ONE_FINISHED) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
    return ret;
}

static int priv_init2(two_t* two, va_list *list) {
    int ret = priv_init1((one_t*)two, list);

    // ...
    while ((selector = va_arg((*list), int)) != INIT_TWO_FINISHED) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...    
    return STATUS_SUCCES;
}

int init_two(two_t* two, ...) {
    int ret;
    va_list list;

    va_start(list, two);
    ret = priv_init2(two, &list);
    va_end(list);

    return ret;
}
```