# va_list argument actually is not a va_list

Tags: c, variadic-functions

When trying to compile this code

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void bar_ptr(int n, va_list *pvl) {
    // do va_arg stuff here
}

void bar(int n, va_list vl) {
    va_list *pvl = &vl; // error here
    bar_ptr(n, pvl);
}

void foo(int n, ...) {
    va_list vl;
    va_list *pvl = &vl; // fine here
    va_start(vl, n);
    bar(n, vl);
    va_end(vl);
}

int main() {
    foo(3, 1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

the GCC compiler prints a warning about `initialization from incompatible pointer type` in the `bar` function. The identical statement is fine in `foo`.

It seems that the type of an agument of type `va_list` is not a `va_list`. This can be tested easily with a static assertion like

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(vl) == sizeof(va_list), "invalid type");
```

in the `bar` function. With GCC, the `_Static_assert` fails. The same can be tested also in C++ with `declytpe` and `std::is_same`.

I would like to take the address of the `va_list vl` argument of `bar`, and pass it as argument of `bar_ptr`, to do thinks like the one described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369588/pass-va-list-or-pointer-to-va-list). On the other hand, it is fine to call `bar_ptr(n, pvl)` directly from `main`, replacing `bar(n, vl)`.

According to the footnote 253 of the [C11 final draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf),

> It is permitted to create a pointer to a `va_list` and pass that
>   pointer to another function

Why this cannot be done if `va_list` is defined as argument of the function, and not in the function body?

**Workaround:**

Even if this does not answer the question, a possible workaround is to change the content of `bar` by using a local copy of the argument created with va_copy:

```
void bar(int n, va_list vl) {
    va_list vl_copy;
    va_copy(vl_copy, vl);
    va_list *pvl = &vl_copy; // now fine here
    bar_ptr(n, pvl);
    va_end(va_copy);
}
```

Comment: Regarding the standards quote you have: You don't actually pass a pointer to a `va_list`.

Comment: *It is permitted to create a pointer to a va_list and pass that pointer to another function*  You're not passing a **pointer** to a `va_list`, you're passing an actual `va_list`.

Comment: I know I'm passing a `va_list`. Suppose I have a third function `void bar_ptr(va_list *pvl);`, I want to pass a pointer to `va_list vl` to that function. I'll edit the question to specify it.

Comment: If you call `bar_ptr` with `&vl` directly (as in `bar_ptr(n, &vl)`) do you get the same error then?

Comment: Also, are you on a 32 or 64 bit system? The `va_list` type can (and probably will) be different on an x86 system compared to an x86-64 system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I get exactly the same error by calling `bar_ptr(n, &vl)`. I'm on a 64 bit system. I've noticed that it [works](https://godbolt.org/z/ieYk6d) when compiled with `-m32`.

Comment: The problem is that, moving to C++ to use its tools, `std::is_same<decltype(vl), va_list>::value` is surprisingly false if used on `bar`.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371450/how-are-variable-arguments-implemented-in-gcc) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958384/what-is-the-format-of-the-x86-64-va-list-structure) question could be helpful. And it's also very likely that the compiler have special handling of `va_list`

Comment: The `va_copy` approach you have is the canonical solution to this problem. I have a few past questions on it that basically concluded this.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE an answer to my question is your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4959184/3287591), even if that question was a little bit different.

Comment: Another solution (C11+ only): `_Generic(vl, va_list: &vl, default: (va_list *)vl)`

Comment: For reference, the discussion about the [GCC bug #14557](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=14557) can be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`va_list` is permitted by the standard to be an array, and often it is.
That means `va_list` in a function parameter gets adjusted to a pointer to whatever `va_list`'s internal first element is.

The weird rule ([7.16p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16p3)) regarding how `va_list` gets passed basically accommodates the possibility that `va_list` might be of an array type or of a regular type.

I personally wrap `va_list` in a `struct` so I don't have to deal with this.

When you then pass pointers to such a `struct va_list_wrapper`, it's basically as if you passed pointers to `va_list`, and then [footnote 253](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#note253) applies which gives you the permission to have both a callee and a caller manipulate the same `va_list` via such a pointer.

(The same thing applies to `jmp_buf` and `sigjmp_buf` from `setjmp.h`. In general, this type of array to pointer adjustment is one of the reasons why array-typed `typedef`s are best avoided. It just creates confusion, IMO.)

Comment: If `va_list` may be an array, it is misleading for the standard to say “The object `ap` may be passed as an argument to another function…” (C 2018 7.16 3, `ap` is an object of type `va_list`).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The standard says a lot of misleading things and considers them not-a-but/WONTFIX as long as the intent is clear to "somebody"... :-P

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just do as suggested by footnote 253 and pass a pointer to the `va_list` instead of the `va_list` itself? That will also work whether or not `va_list` is an array type, and avoids copying a possibly bulky object. (Sorry to comment after so much time. Your answer came up during a search for problems caused by `va_list` sometimes being an array type.)

Comment: @rici Wrapping a might-be-an-array type in a struct gives it more predictable semantics from the user's point of view: passing an address to it gives you reference semantics, passing *it* gives you value semantics and you don't get the highly unintuitive thing where `might_be_an_array_t block_scope_var;` is typed differently from `might_be_an_array_t arg_variable;`. Unfortunately for a `struct wrapped_va_list`, the standard doesn't really guarantee that copies of that will work as expected as the standard wants you to do va_copy+va_end to get a copy of the current state.

Comment: @rici And yes, you usally want reference semantics anyway and it doesn't matter if you get that by passing `struct wrapped_va_list*` or always passing `va_list*` (might as well always pass va_list, because you never get value semantics with it anyway--you either get reference semantics if the caller passing a va_list doesn't use the passed `ap` after the call (other than doing `va_end(ap)` on it) or you get undefined behavior if it tries to use it after passing it to a callee).

Comment: @ric But for the rare case where you do want a copy (in a callee, which might then use subcallees to process parts) passing a `struct wrapped_va_list` might likely get you that without the ensuing weirdness stemming from `va_list param` not really being typed `va_list`. (And it doesn't preclude being proper and using `va_copy`/`va_end` on the member)

Comment: @PSkocik: Suppose that bit-for-bit copying of a `va_list` doesn't work (perhaps because registers are saved into the `va_list` itself, which also contains an internal pointer to the first unused one). Passing the `va_list` by value violates the "no direct copy" requirement, and you no longer have the original in order to perform the legitimate `va_copy`. So I think it does "preclude being proper". (Of course, it's dancing angels, unless there is actually an implementation which works like my imaginary one.)

Comment: @rici What I meant was that merely having a wrapper type doesn't preclude doing `va_copy(dest.member,src.member)` and then passing `&dest`.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution (C11+ only):

```
_Generic(vl, va_list: &vl, default: (va_list *)vl)
```

Explanation: if `vl` has type `va_list`, then `va_list` isn't an array type and just taking the address is fine to get a `va_list *` pointing to it. Otherwise, it must have array type, and then you're permitted to cast a pointer to the first element of the array (whatever type that is) to a pointer to the array.